# SwiftUI: Navigation bar is empty space when scrolling after going out from app and returning

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, tabview

I'm using a custom navigation bar which already has its settings for appearance at SceneDelegate which gives the full transparent effect to simulate no background. I'm applying this style to standard, compact and scroll appearances.

When launching the app it is working as expected but if I go outside from the app and the back it will add an empty space as soon as I start to scroll and space is never fill with its content.
This is only happening when going outside from the app and the back without closing it.

Removing styles for scroll or any other in Navigation Bar causes other problems.

This is how looks when trying to scroll after have gone outside.

[image: navigation bar bug when scrolling]

The structure of the code looks basically like this. At the top there is a TabView holding each screen:

```
TabView {
        HomeView().tabItem { Image("Home") }
    }.accentColor(Color.Theme.TabIcon)
```

Then the Home screen has a simple structure:

```
NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Text("Sample")
                Text("Text")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Products")
    }
```

Settings at SceneDelegate is this:

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BackgroundView")
    navigationBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear

    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "BackgroundView")
    tabBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear

    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

Thanks in advance.